# Filter aggregations in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Say I'm acting on a collection of documents that look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("552712c3f92ea17426000ace"),
    "product" : "Mobile Safari",
    "venue_id" : NumberLong(71540),
    "uid" : "dd542fea6b4443469ff7bf1f56472eac",
    "ag" : 0,
    "promo" : "bc40100abc8d4eb6a0c68f81f4a756c7",
    "promo_f" : NumberLong(1),
    "brand" : NumberLong(17),
    "venue" : "ovation_2480",
    "lt" : 0,
    "ts" : ISODate("2015-04-10T00:01:07.734Z"),
    "evt" : "login",
    "mac" : "00:00:00:00:00:00",
    "__ns__" : "wifipromo",
    "pvdr" : NumberLong(42),
    "os" : "iPhone",
    "cmpgn" : "fc6de34aef8b4f57af0b8fda98d8c530",
    "ip" : "192.119.43.250",
    "lng" : 0,
    "product_ver" : "8"
}
```

I want to count the total amount of aggregate documents with the same uid.
I use this:

```
db.events_2015_04_10.aggregate([

        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$uid",
                count: {
                    $sum: 1
                }
            }        
        }
    ]);
```

But lets say I want only a list of aggregations that don't contain evt: "login." In short I only want to aggregate by uid only if all documents with that uid do not have evt: "login."

how would I do that?

Comment: Please note: I'm not looking to get aggregates minus the {evt: login }.

I want to filter the aggregates so that I only see the aggregations that happened for groups of uids that do NOT contain a {evt: login}

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. Use [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) with the [**`$ne`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) operator.

```js
db.events_2015_04_10.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "evt": { "$ne": "login" }}},
    { "$group": { "_id": "$uid", "count": { "$sum": 1 }}}
])
```

Comment: Doing that I wold get aggregations of uid with the evt:login removed.
What I want is all aggregations except the ones that contain a evt:login...